# Visual Studio Community 2019 installation failed in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Something wrong with my unity as I cannot install vs community via unity hub. Every installation ends up with error. Here's ss with error:[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtU9K.png)

I reinstalled 3 or 4 times, unistalled vs community from pc, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install manually the Visual Studio not through Unity Hub.

After it is installed open your Unity project and on the top Bar go to "Edit->Preferences->External Tools" and there you can find an option "External Script Editor", from there you can choose Visual Studio or any other installed IDE you have, that supports Unity.

You can read more about it from Unity's Official document [here](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/set-your-default-script-editor-ide#)

Comment: Im having same problem as person in [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-community-installer-not-running-working/326811). Turns out it's whole .net problem, not visual studio. Which is kinda weird becouse i could run visual studio code but not visual studio community 2022. Then i uninstalled every visual program i had, hoping to reinstall fresh working community leaving me with no visual studio. I just ran repair tool but still not working.

Comment: The only workaround im able to find for now is to just download vs code as it seems working, right click on script in unity show in explorer and open it in vs code. Ill just reinstal windows in a few days. This should do the thing.

Comment: I would recommend that you use the Rider IDE, which is the one that I use. The only thing is that it's not free unless if you are a student you can get it for free but I think if your willing to work professional in programming it is worth to pay for it. Also it has a dedicated plugin for Unity.